# Trouble with subqueries

Tags: sql

I have got three tables from which I need information. I am trying to get the license plate numbers for certain cars that much follow some guidelines.

[image]

The guidelines are: Cars that dont have any bookings from customers from city x.
                    Cars that do not have any bookings from the table BOOKING.

Would appreciate any help I could get.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.licenseplateNo, Model FROM Car c
JOIN Booking b
ON  c.licenseplateNo = b.licenseplateNo
JOIN Customer c
ON c.customerID = b.customerID
WHERE c.Ort <> 'cityname'
ORDER BY licenseplateNo ASC

SELECT f.licenseplateNo, Model FROM Cars c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT b.licenseplateNo FROM Booking b WHERE b.licenseplateNo = c.licenseplateNo);
```

The problem with this code is shows as two separate questions.

Comment: How do you link `cars` and `bookings` tables?

Comment: Aw crap. licenseplateNo is also under BOOKINGS. Sorry.

Comment: What code I have is in swedish. What I have tried is using NOT EXISTS to extract what LicenseplateNO does not exists in BOOKINGS and that one works.

Comment: Update your diagram, or right it in code....

Comment: I hope this is a bit clearer now.

Comment: The two guidelines do look like they are about two different queries. If a car has no bookings from the table BOOKINGS, it has no bookings *at all*, because it is the BOOKINGS table that stores all of the bookings. So, it doesn't make sense to require that a car have no bookings from city X customers *and* no bookings from the BOOKINGS table: the second requirement covers the first one. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @Read my answer -3rd section. I think he wants the union of the 2 results.

Comment: @meewoK: That still doesn't clarify much, if anything at all, I'm afraid. The subset of cars with no bookings from a particular city will include *all the cars* without any booking. I can't see a point in unioning the two subsets. But hey, your answer did work for the OP, so I'm happy for both of you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cars that don't have any bookings from customers from city x**

```
select *
from bookings b, customers c, cars ca
where b.licenseplateNo = ca.licenseplateNo
and c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
where not c.city = x;
```

**Cars that do not have any bookings from the table BOOKING.**

```
select *
from cars c
where not exists (
  select b.licenseplateNo 
  from bookings b
  where b.licenseplateNo = c.licenseplateNo
);
```

You could also do the second query with a left outer join between cars and bookings and check for null.

**Cars that do not have any bookings from the table BOOKING and don't have any bookings from customers from city x**

The requirement to exclude car from specific booking customer city excludes a subset of the requirement exclude all cars that have a booking.
Hence tge second query takes care of that unless ofcourse we want a UNION of the 2 query results.

You can perform a Union of the two queries to get the combined results.

Another better option is to modify your 1st query to use a left join between car and booking and add an or check for null in your where.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.licenseplateNo, Model
FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN Booking b
ON c.licenseplateNo = b.licenseplateNo
LEFT JOIN Customer c
ON c.customerID = b.customerID
WHERE c.Ort <> 'cityname'
OR c.Ort is NULL
ORDER BY licenseplateNo ASC;
```

Comment: Is there a way I could go about so that I have it within the same query?

Comment: updated answer. Can someone format the code because can't from iphone.

Comment: Hi. This brings out the results I am looking for. Thanks! I do however not understand how    "c.Ort is NULL"  gives me the results of the cars that has yet to be booked at all.

Comment: This is because of the left joins. Left joins mean all cars are displayed. However , for xars with no bookings, the booking and customer table columns are null. If you used normal joins this would not work as only cars with bookings, and bookings with customers, would br displayed.